# Is there anything wrong with the sentence "今午前七時間です"?

Tags: grammar, words, time, learning, help

I'm reviewing the first section of Lingodeer by redoing all the tests. It wanted me to type out "It's 7 a.m. now." I typed this in and got it wrong.

The correct answer was simply to remove 間, so what am I misunderstanding about the usage here? I looked around elsewhere for explanations on its usage, but couldn't find anything beginner friendly enough to understand properly.

In case anyone is wondering how far Lingodeer 1 goes, it's somewhere around the start of Genki 2, so that's where I'm at.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding 間 turns a fixed point in time into a period of time. "It's 7 o'clock" is a fixed time so it would just be 七時. You would add 間 if you wanted to say that you'd been doing something for seven hours, for example.